# QNAP QTS: static ip connection

Tags: nas, qnap

Recently I just purchased a NAS device for my company. So far, everything is fine and the quality of it is superb. The only problem that I encounter is, when I trying to access the static IP that I choose still can connect in my own company, but when I try to connect the same IP in my house, it just won't went in the same interfaces. Is this because of my NAS device setup in my company connect through local connection? And I am a newbie towards the NAS device so hope to have any solver soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your house LAN you don't have access to your company LAN.

I have a Qnap Nas and I normally connect with [myqnapcloud.com](https://myqnapcloud.com/) You need to sign up, configure your qnap with the router at your company and link it through myqnapcloud.com.

I have my Qnap on my home and I use that way when stay outside my home, you can use the web to use your Qnap. I advise you to buy ssl license to login securely

Hope it works to you!